# How to Display Pyramid Pattern in Text View in Android..?

Tags: android, textview

How to display the below output in Text View ?

```
    *
   * *
  * * *
 * * * *
* * * * *
```

Comment: Wht do u want exactly

Comment: Provide proper details in question.

Comment: There are *many* duplicates of this question, in a multitude of languages and environments. The solution is easily found on the greater Internet as well.

Comment: Also, *do* take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I cant find .U have any link .. ?

Comment: It's only a nested for loop. You can make it very easily.

Comment: I tired that.I am getting pyramid pattern when i use System . out.print() .. But how to display in Text View.????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here you go!

in your xml file.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtPattern"
    android:height="wrap_content"
    android:width="wrap_content" />
```

In your class file's onCreate() write below code :

```
String temp = "";
TextView pattern = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPattern);

for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    String t = "";
    for(int j=0; j<=i; j++)
    {
        t = t + "*"; 
    }
    temp = temp + t + "\n";
}

pattern.setText(temp);
```

If any issue or correction let me know or answer resolves your problem please mark this answer.

Happy Coding!